# Unable to serialize Avro schema when we have an array with null objects

Tags: avro, avsc

I have list of objects, out of which one object is null. When I am trying to serialize the below data, I am getting

`null of string of array of union of`

`[object1, object2, object3, null, object4]`

Schema Definition

```
{
    "name": "myList",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": "string"
        }
      ],
    "default": null
}
```

How do we allow or ignore the null in the list/array and avoid the error ? TIA

Comment: What do you mean "ignore the null"? You can simply check null values before you append to the list in your client code before you serialize the data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to also add `null` as a possible value in the array?

```
{
    "name": "myList",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ]
        }
      ],
    "default": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried this but it's breaking the backward compatibility with the previous schema versions. Unless it don't break that, we are not registering the  new schema. So unable to test though